# why does saving an image to an array and reloading it doesn't show the same image?

Tags: python, arrays, image, csv

I want to save an image (image: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i7ZK.png)) to an array, save the array in .csv format and then load the .csv file to a different array and show the image.
But the image at the end isn't the image I saved before. Instead I just see stripes and squares...   [the picture at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1hod.png)

code:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

#saving the image to an array
a = np.array(Image.open("C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\1.png").convert("L"))

#showing the image from array
image = Image.fromarray(a, "L")
image.show()

#saving the array to .csv file
array_save = np.savetxt("C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\array_save.csv", a, delimiter=",")
array = np.loadtxt("C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\array_save.csv", delimiter=",")
array = array.astype(int)

#showing the image from array put of the .csv file
image = Image.fromarray(array, "L")
image.show()
```

I really don't know why I don't see the image. The arrays should be the same and when I print them out they look the same to me.

Comment: please format the code so that it is readable, add `\```python` at the top and `\`\`\`` at the bottom of Your code (those are backticks btw and NOT quotation marks)

Comment: Seems crazy to open a PIL Image, make it into a Numpy array only to change it back into a PIL Image. I would replace first 2 lines with `image = Image.open().convert()` then `a = np.array(image)`

Answer (score 1):

The `a` array created is of type `uint8`, but when you recreate the array from the CSV file you are specifying `int`. Change this to `np.uint8` and it should work:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

#saving the image to an array
a = np.array(Image.open("1.png").convert("L"))

print(a.dtype)   # show the array type
#showing the image from array
image = Image.fromarray(a, "L")
image.show()

#saving the array to .csv file
array_save = np.savetxt("array_save.csv", a, delimiter=",")
array = np.loadtxt("array_save.csv", delimiter=",")
array = array.astype(np.uint8)

#showing the image from array put of the .csv file
image = Image.fromarray(array, "L")
image.show()
```